# Where is this error message coming from: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract np.max(np.abs(fsim[0] - fsim[1:])) <= fatol):

Tags: python, minimize

Why do i get this error message "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
np.max(np.abs(fsim[0] - fsim[1:])) <= fatol):" with in this code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.stats import weibull_min
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed()
shape_true = 2.9
scale_true = 1101.0
location_true = 40.0
size = 1000
data = weibull_min.rvs(shape_true, scale=scale_true, loc=location_true, size=size)

def weibull_likelihood(params):
    scale, shape, loc = params
    ll = np.sum(np.log(weibull_min.pdf(data - loc, shape, loc=0, scale=scale)))
    return -ll

initial_guess = [1, 1, 1]  # Anfangsschätzung für die Parameter
result = minimize(weibull_likelihood, initial_guess, method='Nelder-Mead')

estimated_scale, estimated_shape, estimated_loc = result.x

print("Geschätzter Formparameter (shape):", estimated_shape)
print("Geschätzter Skalierungsfaktor (scale):", estimated_scale)
print("Geschätzter Lageparameter (location):", estimated_loc)
```

I am wondering why this code runs perfect if i reduce this variable:

```
scale_true = 1101.0 to     scale_true = 111.0
```

Where is the key problem?